# llama.cpp: Inference time a lot higher when using cmake compared to w64devkit

Tags: cmake

For certain reasons, the inference time of my `mistral-orca` is a lot longer when having compiled the binaries with `cmake` compared to `w64devkit`. What could be the cause of this? I'm using a macbook pro, 2019 with an i7. I want to run the inference on CPU only.

```
w64devkid:
llama_print_timings: load time = 2789.31 ms
llama_print_timings: sample time = 7.55 ms / 18 runs ( 0.42 ms per token, 2383.16 tokens per second)
llama_print_timings: prompt eval time = 1925.06 ms / 20 tokens ( 96.25 ms per token, 10.39 tokens per second)
llama_print_timings: eval time = 8256.93 ms / 18 runs ( 458.72 ms per token, 2.18 tokens per second)
llama_print_timings: total time = 23842.73 ms
```

```
cmake:
llama_print_timings: load time = 4133.27 ms
llama_print_timings: sample time = 5.71 ms / 18 runs ( 0.32 ms per token, 3153.47 tokens per second)
llama_print_timings: prompt eval time = 25917.85 ms / 19 tokens ( 1364.10 ms per token, 0.73 tokens per second)
llama_print_timings: eval time = 43493.77 ms / 18 runs ( 2416.32 ms per token, 0.41 tokens per second)
llama_print_timings: total time = 74989.23 ms
```

I compiled them on my macbook with the `cmake` and `make`. I expect the inference to be about the same speed.

Comment: It's highly possible that the project is compiled with different optimizations in cmake and make file. And sometimes cmake and make file are not even synced in the same project.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! As I'm not super familiar with cmake and make, how can I align those optimizations?

Comment: I am afraid I can't help you, as I am unfamiliar with `mistral-orca`. Is it a open source project? I think you can get more help from the maintainer of this project. The best you can do here is to post the link to the repository, and its cmake and make files.

Comment: This is the repository: https://github.com/ggerganov/llama.cpp. I saw that I forgot to mention I am using a C-Library called llama.cpp to run my mistral-orca large language model. I want to compile this llama.cpp using cmake. For some reason it's with whatever optimization flag i select a lot slower.